# memory leak situation in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak when i call a method that return me a string----
the method definition is as follows

```
-(NSMutableArray *)read
{
NSMutableArray  *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//picking data from database here


return dataArray;
}
```

this show a big memory leak
i also tried--- `NSMutableArray  *dataArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];`

but this time leack checking process gets hanged

i also cannot release that array before return

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)read
{
    NSMutableArray  *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //picking data from database here

    return dataArray;
}
```

Anything that uses the method `read` will expect to get back an object it does not own.  However, as written here, dataArray is still owned at the point of return.  You can't release it because that might make it go away altogether.  You must, in this instance autorelease the array.  You can either do this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)read
{
    NSMutableArray  *dataArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    //picking data from database here

    return dataArray;
}
```

or this

```
-(NSMutableArray *)read
{
    NSMutableArray  *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //picking data from database here

    return [dataArray autorelease];
}
```

You say "leak checking process get hanged" but I'm really not sure what you mean by that.  Whether it hangs, crashes or plays the Botswana National Anthem, you definitely need to autorelease the returned array and any other problem is actually a different problem.  Possibly, you are forgetting to retain the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer more...
There are many conventions in cocoa/cocoa-touch, there is [one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW2) of them that says that if a method has the prefix `init` then you will have the ownership of that object (hence you have to release it)

This is NOT your case, hence if you do:

```
DatabaseReader *dbReader = [[DatabaseReader alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [dbReader read];
[dbReader release];
```

you are NOT supposed to release `mutArray`. BUT, the object created HAS to be released by someone. So you can do as JeremyP wrote. alloc/init and put it into a autorelease pool inside read method implementation. Or, you can do:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)read
{
    NSMutableArray  *dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    //IMPORTANT:
    //Did you noticed that I am not using any method 
    //with init prefix for the creation of dataArray ? 
    //so I don't need to release by my self ;)

    //picking data from database here

    return dataArray;
}
```

Which is basically the same. ;)

Comment: This isn't quite right. Ownership is acquired by the `alloc` class method, not by the `init` instance method. See the documentation for NSObject's [alloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-alloc) method and also refer to the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Answer (score -1):

Ownership of the returned object may be returned to the object that receives from this function. You may do some debugging with the object's retain count using something like this...

```
NSLog(@"Retain count: %i", [dataArray retainCount]);
```

Turn on the debugging console (Command + R in Xcode) to see the NSLog output.

Comment: I'd recommend against caring about an object's retain count; due to things beyond our control, the retain count is not that useful from a debugging perspective. It's there so the object knows when to deallocate itself.

Comment: +1 @Jonathan is correct, and even Apple's documentation for the `retainCount` method says not to use it for debugging memory management issues. One of its potential issues is that it does not take into account pending `autorelease`s.

Comment: DO NOT CALL retainCount.  Not ever and certainly **not** for "debugging purposes".

Comment: Why the hell is it there then?

Comment: If you don't want your object to be ever be deallocated, one of the recommended things to do is to overrride `retainCount` to return `UINT_MAX`, and also override `retain` and `release` to do nothing. The actual `retainCount` value is looked at by the framework I guess.